# Login Form in asp.net will not direct to login page

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Basically I'm using the login form provided in visual studio and trying to authenticate using a sql database. If I input incorrect data the correct validation appears, however when I put in the correct data at the moment it just refreshes the current form rather than taking note of the destinationUrl part.

I'm at a loss in how to fix this now...help

Below is my forms code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace com.tortoise.Admin.AdminViews
{
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private string strcon = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TortoiseDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
        private bool UserLogin(string un, string pw)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Username from Admins where Username=@un and Password=@pw", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@un", un);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pw", pw);
        con.Open();
        string result = Convert.ToString(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(result)) return false; return true;
    }
    protected void Login1_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
    {
        string un = Login1.UserName;
        string pw = Login1.Password;
        bool result = UserLogin(un, pw);
        if (result)
        {
            e.Authenticated = true;
            Session["username"] = un;
            Login1.DestinationPageUrl =
           String.Format("Manager.aspx?{0}", Request.QueryString.ToString());

        }

        else e.Authenticated = false;
    }

    protected void SqlDataSource1_Selecting(object sender, SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Try `String.Format("~/Manager.aspx?{0}", ...` I've always used `Response.Redirect`

Comment: i've never used anything, q-string has always been filled-in and redirection always automatic. there might be something in web.config you need to add, sry i forget what right now, or maybe delete and re-add the login control.

Comment: p.s. you can use a separate log-in and web.config for admin area.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Will try out some of your suggestions. Will come back with the results

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string returnUrl = Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"];
 if (returnUrl == null) returnUrl = @"~/yourfirstpage.aspx";
     Response.Redirect(returnUrl);
```